# Generic .htaccess www.redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, regex

There are plenty of examples here of how to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`, but I'm looking for a generic version, so the same htacess code would also work to redirect `example.net` to `www.example.net` and `example.org` to `www.example.org`. I'm sure this exists (indeed, I have a vague memory I've done it before, somewhere), but I'm fairly unfamiliar with htaccess regex.

I need a way to match the condition `HTTP_HOST` does not begin with `www.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Enable RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On

# For a way to check HTTP_HOST not beginning with www:    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [nc]

# As ! don't set backreferences we use this to match the hostname we need
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [nc]

# For the Redirect itself:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is breaking on me, redirecting to `http:///`. Could this be because I have a three-part domain name (`draft.example.net` to `www.draft.example.net`)?

Comment: I think the backreference to %1 did not work correctly. You might try with the updated code snippet.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test that as soon as I can. (FTP server is down right now.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question on stackoverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www